# dpkg says adobe-flashplugin not installed

Tags: installation, flash, dependencies, adobe

I've tried installing `adobe-flash-properties-gtk` using *dpkg*. It says the dependency `adobe-flashplugin` is missing.
Despite having Adobe Flash working properly, `dpkg -l | grep flash` only returns `flashplugin-installer (install ok installed)` and `adobe-flash-properties-gtk (install ok unpacked)`
Where is my `adobe-flashplugin`?

PS: I've been messing around with Gnash and Lightspark a bit a few weeks ago, and restored adobe flash afterwards.

Raring x64

Answer (score 0):

It is because that **Flashplugin Installer** already installed.

It is being removed if **Adobe Flashplugin** is installed.

Comment: So you're saying, that after installing the flash plugin using the flashplugin-installer, `adobe-flashplugin` gets removed. Did I get this correctly? This wouldn't make any sense, would it?

Comment: Yes. Both are doing the same thing. So when one get installed, other is being removed by that process.